# Is locally compact space Hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology

In [this proof](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/proper+maps+to+locally+compact+spaces+are+closed) of the statement that proper maps to locally compact spaces are closed, the fact that compact subspaces of Hausdorff spaces are closed is used. However, is it true that locally compact spaces are Hausdorff?

Comment: No. For example the trivial topology is compact but not Hausdorff (if it has more than 2 elements)

Comment: Exactly 2 elements works as well: the space $\{0,1\}$ with topology $\{\varnothing,\{0,1\}\}$ is compact (thus locally compact) but not Hausdorff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The discussion on local compactness on its [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_space) is quite relevant to this question. It discusses the three common non-equivalent (in general spaces) definitional variants of *local compactness*, and notes that these are all equivalent for Hausdorff ($T_2$) spaces, and this is part of the reason that Hausdorffness and local compactness are often assumed together (the property behaves better wrt operations and the combination implies Tychonoff (completely regular), and the Alexandroff compactification (one-point compactification) is better behaved, among others..)

The definition of the OP (in the link) is definition variant $2''$: every point has a local base of relatively compact neighbourhoods.

The Alexandroff compactification of $\Bbb Q$ is an example of a $T_1$ space that is locally compact in senses $1$ and $2$ (so also loc. compact according to the OP, as $2''$ is equivalent to $2$) but not Hausdorff. That example answers the title's question.

Answer (score 2):

To clarify the definitions, a topological space $(X,\tau)$ is **compact** if every collection of open sets (i.e. elements of $\tau$) whose union is $X$ has a finite subcollection whose union is still $X$. The space is **locally compact** if for all $x\in X$ there exists an open set $U\in \tau$ and a subset $K\subseteq X$ such that $\{x\}\subseteq U\subseteq K$ and the subspace topology $(K,\tau|_K)$ is compact. A topological space $(X,\tau)$ is **Hausdorff** if for all $x,y\in X$ such that $x\not=y$, there exist open sets $U,V\in \tau$ such that $U\cap V=\varnothing$ and $x\in U$ and $y\in V$.

The following example of a locally compact space which is not Hausdorff was suggested in the comments.

**Claim.** Let $X$ be any set that contains at least $2$ distinct elements, and let $\tau=\{\varnothing,X\}$ be the topology whose only open sets are the empty set and $X$ itself. Then $(X,\tau)$ is locally compact but non-Hausdorff.

**Proof.** Since there are only finitely many open sets in $(X,\tau)$, this is a compact topological space. Every compact space is locally compact, since we can take $K=X$ in the definition of local compactness. The space is not Hausdorff since it contains two distinct elements $x\not=y$ (by assumption) and the only choices for $U,V$ containing $x,y$ is $U=V=X$ (since that is the only open set which is non-empty). But then $U\cap V\not=\varnothing$, so the space is not Hausdorff.

Comment: Does locally compact + $T_1$ (finite sets are closed) imply Hausdorff?

Comment: The definition in the link of local compactness is different: for all $x$ and all open neighbourhoods $U$ of $x$ there is an open neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ with compact closure and such that $\overline{V}\subseteq U$. This is stronger than what you state as the definition. The trivial topology is still a simple counterexample to the Hausdorff question.

Comment: @Math1000 no, see my answer..

Comment: Your local compactness is variant 1, the OP's is variant 2.